# EventListener calling a function() prematurely

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

My EventListener is calling the function before the click with this code... what's wrong with that line?

It was working fine when I had the function inside the parameter, but now that i'm calling it from there instead it's calling it prematurely before any click occurs.

```
divs[i].addEventListener('click', xopush(i), null);
```

It's calling a function with and argument passing to the function()... not an alert.

Comment: It should be `divs[i].addEventListener('click', xopush, null);` with no parens `()`. And the `, null` part should be either `true` or `false` (but this is not the problem).

Comment: I need it to pass that argument is why...

Comment: When you solve the above issue, and assuming by the looks of your code that you are using a loop, you'll end up having [**this very famous issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: Then pass it as an anonymous function... `('click', function() { xopush(i); }, null)`

Comment: Yea, it's definitely within a loop. Solving one leads to a following issue because if I take out the argument it won't run the way I coded it to run in sequence. I'll have to get that argument passed otherwise.

Comment: It the same problem, in your case it's `xopush` and in the duplicate it's `alert`. Same way to fix too.

Comment: I hate to answer a dupe question so here is the answer in comment: `for(...) { (function(i) { divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() { xopush(i); }, false); })(i); }`. This should solve both problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Instead of EventListener I usually prefer to use...

divs[i].onclick = function() {
    xopush(i);
}
```

... which is a answer to this. However, I was looking forward to using the eventListener so I could turn it off after 1 click on the element.

Comment: You can do the same using `addEventListener`. Please remove this answer. If you want to add something add it in the question, unless ofcourse, it is a valid answer that solves the problem.

Comment: Well, the onclick does solve this issue on its own. However, removing the addEventListener as the solution also removes the possibility of remove.

Comment: Your suggested solution for this actually creates the initial issue which led to this question. This anonymous function cannot be removed in the removeEventListener syntax. @ibrahimmahrir